# Disappearing BorderIcons on closing an MDI child

Tags: delphi, icons, mdichild

I'm in the process of "upgrading" a Delphi 2007 MDI application to Delphi 11.

I noticed the following behavior when closing an MDI child. When clicking the close icon, the icon menu disappears. Not a big thing, unless you have an `OnClose` event handler that prevents the Form from closing. Then the border icons do not come back. Even after I added the line:

`BorderIcons := [biSystemMenu,biMinimize,biMaximize];`

```
procedure TFrmSingleParts.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
var
  wMsg: Word;
begin
  if (BcStockPart1.State = bcsInsert) then
  begin
    wMsg := gblPmsMessage.Show('ADDSTOCK', dmtConfirmation, [dmbYes, dmbNo, dmbCancel], 0);
    case wMsg of
    mrYes:
    begin
      BcStockPart1.Post;
      Action := caFree
    end;
    mrNo:
    begin
      BcStockPart1.Cancel;
      Action := caFree
    end;
    mrCancel:
    begin
      Action := caNone;
      BorderIcons := [biSystemMenu,biMinimize,biMaximize];
    end;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    Action := caFree;
  end;
end;
```

Any suggestions on how to restore the `BorderIcons` if the Form is not actually closed?

Comment: And this is surely a Delphi version problem? The operating system and all its theming is still the same?

Comment: This is clearly a bug in the VCL in Delphi 11. You should [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero. That being said, MDI is *ancient*, Microsoft abandoned it years ago, and support for it in modern Windows versions is very spotty at best. Not to mention that Embarcadero has many open tickets regarding MDI bugs. You really shouldn't be using MDI anymore in modern coding.

Comment: @Remy, I have a large userbase for this application. Could you suggest an alternative to an MDI with multiple main windows that wouldn't create a big culture shock.

Comment: You know the answer: nowadays tabs are en vogue, most commonly known from web browsers. With the downside of not being freely sizable anymore, so one cannot arrange multiple documents to view all of them at the same time. The other answer: just use regular windows and add your own "Window" menu to provide auto arrange features (like tiling).

Comment: Hmmm, in other words, still functionally an MDI, without the technical advantages of MDI. But I thank y'all for your thoughts.